# How can i make Entity Framework TPT inheritance to build one table per each type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make an inheritance TPT Entity Framework to build tables for each type.i searched the site and saw all but the code i based by them will only build one table for all
here is my classes

```
    public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MainFooProp { get; set; }
}

public class FooA : Foo
{
    public int FooAProp { get; set; }
}

public class FooB : Foo
{
    public int FoobProp { get; set; }
}
```

and my Context is

```
 public DbSet<FooA> FooAs { get; set; }
 public DbSet<FooB> FooBs { get; set; }
```

and in modelBuilder i used

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foos")
        .Map<FooA>(fa => fa.Requires("FooType").HasValue(1))
        .Map<FooB>(fb => fb.Requires("FooType").HasValue(2));
```

i want it to build one table for each including Foo
**it should make something like this diagram**
[diagram of what i really want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjAp.png)

but unfortunately it only makes one table including all properties.
sorry guys but i really desperate to make it work

Comment: not sure what version of EF you're using, but i don't think this is a feature for EF core as of yet.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is removed so I  the solution I used

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foos") 
modelBuilder.Entity<FooA>().ToTable("Foos")
modelBuilder.Entity<FooB>().ToTable("Foos")1
```